# why am I getting this error from importing libraries?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I ran a Classification And Regression Tree (CART) code yesterday that worked perfectly. Today, I am getting the following error after importing the libraries below without changing anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_7048/1297423964.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 import seaborn as sn
----> 7 from sklearn import datasets
      8 from sklearn import metrics
      9 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\__init__.py in <module>
     20 from .lfw import fetch_lfw_pairs
     21 from .lfw import fetch_lfw_people
---> 22 from .twenty_newsgroups import fetch_20newsgroups
     23 from .twenty_newsgroups import fetch_20newsgroups_vectorized
     24 from .mldata import fetch_mldata, mldata_filename

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\datasets\twenty_newsgroups.py in <module>
     42 from .base import _fetch_remote
     43 from .base import RemoteFileMetadata
---> 44 from ..feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
     45 from ..preprocessing import normalize
     46 from ..utils import deprecated

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py in <module>
      8 from .hashing import FeatureHasher
      9 from .image import img_to_graph, grid_to_graph
---> 10 from . import text
     11 
     12 __all__ = ['DictVectorizer', 'image', 'img_to_graph', 'grid_to_graph', 'text',

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <module>
     26 
     27 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
---> 28 from ..preprocessing import normalize
     29 from .hashing import FeatureHasher
     30 from .stop_words import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py in <module>
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from ._function_transformer import FunctionTransformer
      7 
      8 from .data import Binarizer

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_function_transformer.py in <module>
      3 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
      4 from ..utils import check_array
----> 5 from ..utils.testing import assert_allclose_dense_sparse
      6 
      7 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\testing.py in <module>
    716 
    717 try:
--> 718     import pytest
    719 
    720     skip_if_32bit = pytest.mark.skipif(_IS_32BIT,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytest.py in <module>
      4 """
      5 from _pytest import __version__
----> 6 from _pytest.assertion import register_assert_rewrite
      7 from _pytest.config import cmdline
      8 from _pytest.config import hookimpl

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\__init__.py in <module>
      4 import sys
      5 
----> 6 from _pytest.assertion import rewrite
      7 from _pytest.assertion import truncate
      8 from _pytest.assertion import util

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py in <module>
     18 from _pytest._io.saferepr import saferepr
     19 from _pytest._version import version
---> 20 from _pytest.assertion import util
     21 from _pytest.assertion.util import (  # noqa: F401
     22     format_explanation as _format_explanation,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\util.py in <module>
      3 from collections.abc import Sequence
      4 
----> 5 import _pytest._code
      6 from _pytest import outcomes
      7 from _pytest._io.saferepr import saferepr

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py in <module>
      1 """ python inspection/code generation API """
----> 2 from .code import Code  # noqa
      3 from .code import ExceptionInfo  # noqa
      4 from .code import filter_traceback  # noqa
      5 from .code import Frame  # noqa

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py in <module>
      9 
     10 import attr
---> 11 import pluggy
     12 import py
     13 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\__init__.py in <module>
     14 ]
     15 
---> 16 from .manager import PluginManager, PluginValidationError
     17 from .callers import HookCallError
     18 from .hooks import HookspecMarker, HookimplMarker

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py in <module>
      4 import warnings
      5 
----> 6 import importlib_metadata
      7 
      8 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in <module>
    464 
    465 
--> 466 __version__ = version(__name__)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in version(package)
    431         "Version" metadata key.
    432     """
--> 433     return distribution(package).version
    434 
    435 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in distribution(package)
    404     :return: A ``Distribution`` instance (or subclass thereof).
    405     """
--> 406     return Distribution.from_name(package)
    407 
    408 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in from_name(cls, name)
    173         """
    174         for resolver in cls._discover_resolvers():
--> 175             dists = resolver(name)
    176             dist = next(dists, None)
    177             if dist is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\importlib_metadata\__init__.py in find_distributions(self, context)
    884         of directories ``context.path``.
    885         """
--> 886         found = self._search_paths(context.name, context.path)
    887         return map(PathDistribution, found)
    888 

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

after running each line singly, I noticed the error started at line 4 (from sklearn import datasets)

why is this?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you updated some module and it doesn't work correctly with older code. You didn't show FULL error message, and we can't read in your mind, so it is hard to say what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have edited the initial post to capture the full error message